# Set global environment variable from json file in travis yml config?

Tags: node.js, sh, travis-ci

I am trying to get the following env variable to be set from a json file when triggered from a release tag.

**.travis.yml**

```
env:
  global:
    - PACKAGE_VERSION=$(if [ -n "$TRAVIS_TAG" ]; then node -p require('./meta.json').deploy_version; else echo "next"; fi)
```

But Travis is giving these errors on build:

```
$ export PACKAGE_VERSION=$(if [ -n "$TRAVIS_TAG" ]; then node -p require('./meta.json')
/home/travis/.travis/functions: eval: line 104: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
/home/travis/.travis/functions: eval: line 105: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

---

**meta.json**

```
{
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "deploy_version": "v3"
}
```

And I want `PACKAGE_VERSION` to be set to `v3` when triggered from a tag/release otherwise set `PACKAGE_VERSION` to `next`.

Thanks in adavance for any help given!

Comment: I think you want to quote the argument to node here. So something like so: 
         PACKAGE_VERSION=$(if [ -n "$TRAVIS_TAG" ]; then node -p "require('./meta.json').deploy_version"; else echo "next"; fi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck on the same issue,  was able to get it to work by moving the node bit into it's own script like so:

file ver.js

```
const {version} = require("./package.json");
console.log(version);
```

In travis.yml

```
env:
  global:
    - PACKAGE_VERSION=$(node ver -p)
```